# Creating a layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

im trying to set that kind of layout: 3 images displayed horizontally, and numbers in the next row displayed under those images.

Here's the wanted layout:
[image]
Here's my current xml layout, that displays the images fine, but the numbers are not right under the images, how can I do that?
(you can copy it to a new project and watch the layout)the layout:
http://pastebin.com/aYb8eeQn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go.

I used a horizontal LinearLayout with `android:weightSum="3"`, and each child with a `android:layout_weight="1"`. 
Notice also that the width of the childred is `android:layout_width="0dip"`.

The second image is way bigger that the other two.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:background="#333"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/wonders_of_zen" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wouldn't that affect the picture sizes?

Comment: @idish I don't understand, what do you mean by affecting picture sizes?

Comment: Oh I thought it will resize the images, but because of the scaleType="centerInside" it doesn't. alright thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just set up evenly-spaced `LinearLayout`s within a horizontal `LinearLayout`. Something like this (not complete, just an outline):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView /> <!-- first image -->
        <TextView /> <!-- 1 -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Repeat the above LinearLayout as many times as you like -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the time to use one big huge RelativeLayout. I'll show you for two images, just keep extending the pattern for more.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/emptystar" />
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/emptystar" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img1"
        android:alignParentRight="True"/>
   <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img1"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
   <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

dont worry, try as follows

First create inner layout as per your need,

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wc" ...height="wc" orientation="vertical">
//Here place your image view
<ImageButton ..width="48dp" ..height="48dp" />

//Then place your text view
<TextView ..width="match_parent" ..height="wc" ..gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

duplicate this layout in relative layout and provide appropriate positions. otherwise place duplicated layouts inside in another Linear Layout (default orientation) as follows

```
<LinearLayout ....>
         <LinearLayout ...... orientation="vertical">
             <ImageButton ...... />
             <TextView ......... />
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout ...... orientation="vertical">
             <ImageButton ...... />
             <TextView ......... />
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout ...... orientation="vertical">
             <ImageButton ...... />
             <TextView ......... />
         </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```